# JavaScript: Using OmniGrid with loadData

Tags: javascript, omnigrid

I'm trying to work with the nice [OmniGrid](http://www.omnisdata.com/omnigrid/) control.
Everything is great when I'm setting a URL for an ASP.NET handler that returns an answer.
My problem starts when I'm trying to use the data provider.

I was breaking my fingers trying to find a piece of information of how to use the data provider (can't find the appropriate format of the table content result).

Anyone familiar with such tutorial/example?

Answer (score 0):

My I know how you are trying to integrate it in your pages? and what kind of backed u have to bind?